# max_file_uploads working

Tags: php

How does `max_file_uploads` work?

> The `php.ini` files says 'Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request'. ([link](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.max-file-uploads))

So does this mean that each user registered at out site will be able to upload 20 files at once or is 20 the total number of files that can be uploaded at once for the entire site. So if registered user 1 is uploading 20 files and registered user 2 is uploading 20 files at the same time, will thing work or stop working for one of them?

I'll be on shared hosting. I'm a little confused with the 'single request' part.

Comment: The maximum number of files allowed to be uploaded simultaneously. Starting with PHP 5.3.4, upload fields left blank on submission do not count towards this limit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per request means every HTTP request made to the application.

Requests are not per registered user or anything. A request is every transmission send via HTTP to your server. Whenever someone uses your file upload page, s/he can upload as many files as the setting permits in that go. Once these files are uploaded (or even while they are uploading), the user can upload another 20 (or whatever the setting is) in separate request.

Comment: So in that case if both users were uploading 20 files each all would go on well. Right?

Comment: @Norman yes, each would go well, because each users would upload in separate requests.

Comment: Same user can upload more than 20 files when he opens upload page more than once.